# SQL select with one clause subordinate to other

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, select

I have a table of quarterback statistics. Each row in the table represents one QB's performance in one game. The unique ID for each row is called gameId and is composed of the player's ID plus the game date.

What I want to do is use a select statement to generate a list of all unique quarterbacks in the table, who have thrown at least one completion.

I'm trying to do that with this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM swdata
WHERE gameComp > 0 AND gameId IN (
   SELECT MAX(gameId) FROM swdata GROUP BY playerId)
ORDER BY playerLastName
```

The first clause is gameComp > 0, and the second clause is to winnow the list down to unique quarterbacks.

What I want to happen is for the first clause to be run, and then for the second clause to be run on the results of the first clause.

But what's actually happening is that they run concurrently, and this results in some players being omitted from the results.

So, I know I've structured it wrong. Can anyone help me get it right?

Comment: Your query is looking for the players who threw at least one completion in their most recent game.

Comment: Exactly. So how can I structure it to select unique quarterbacks who have thrown at least one completion?

Comment: Like Gordon Linoff suggested.  If you have the player name in the SWdata table, your data is badly under-normalized.  The player name should be in a table that defines the player ID; the swdata table should only contain the player ID.  `SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c FROM Wherever` means that only unique combinations of `a, b, c` will be selected; the DISTINCT applies to all the columns in the select-list, not just the leading column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want unique playerIds, wouldn't the following work?

```
select distinct playerId
from swdata
where gamecomp > 0
```

If you want more than one column, then join back to the original table, with a query such as:

```
select s.*
from swdata s join
     (select playerId, max(gameId) as maxgameId
      from swdata
      group by playerId
     ) m
     on s.gameId = maxgameId
```

This is in response to your question about `distinct`.  The distinct returns the distinct values of everything in the select clause.  So, the following are equivalent:

```
select distinct playerID, playerLastName, playerFirstName
from swdata
```

and

```
select playerID, playerLastName, playerFirstName
from swdata
group by playerID, playerLastName, playerFirstName
```

Both of these return all unique combinations of the three columns that appear in the data.

Comment: That's pretty close to what I want. But I want more than just that one column. I'd also like the player name and a couple other things. Is there a way to get that using the distinct keyword?

Comment: I don't understand the second query you posted. But the first one seems really close. It seems like this is what I want: 
SELECT DISTINCT playerId,playerFirstName,playerLastName FROM swdata WHERE gamecomp > 0 ORDER BY playerLastName

Comment: @Kirkman14 . . . Oh, that would probably work too.  You didn't specify what fields you want, so the second query returns all the fields from one of the records in swdata.  Your distinct will work, assuming that a player does not change names.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer, but can you help me understand DISTINCT? So if I put multiple columns after SELECT DISTINCT, is it only looking for a distinct value in the first field I specify?